# How do I find the original source for a facebook page using iframe

Tags: facebook-iframe, facebook-page

When a Facebook page is created inside of an iframe there is an original source host for the files and Facebook caches the files on its own server.

I wanted to access original sources so I can see the coding to duplicate some of the functions on that particular page.

How can I do this if possible

Answer (score 0):

Right click with fireworks and choose "this frame" then choose "show only this frame" ...then view page source.  That should give you the original source code.  The frame viewed by itself should take you to where the developer hosted the original files.